# "Out of memory" in hibrid MPI/OpenMP for GPU acceleration

Tags: out-of-memory, gpu, mpi, openmp

I have compiled Quantum ESPRESSO (Program PWSCF v.6.7MaX) for GPU acceleration (hibrid MPI/OpenMP) with the next options:

```
module load compiler/intel/2020.1
module load hpc_sdk/20.9

./configure F90=pgf90 CC=pgcc MPIF90=mpif90 --with-cuda=yes --enable-cuda-env-check=no --with-cuda-runtime=11.0 --with-cuda-cc=70 --enable-openmp BLAS_LIBS='-lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core'

make -j8 pw
```

Apparently, the compilation ends succesfully. Then, I execute the program:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
mpirun -n 2 /home/my_user/q-e-gpu-qe-gpu-6.7/bin/pw.x < silverslab32.in > silver4.out
```

Then, the program starts running and print out the next info:

```
Parallel version (MPI & OpenMP), running on       8 processor cores
Number of MPI processes:                 2
Threads/MPI process:                     4
...
GPU acceleration is ACTIVE
...
Estimated max dynamical RAM per process >      13.87 GB
Estimated total dynamical RAM >      27.75 GB
```

But after 2 minutes of execution the job ends with error:

```
0: ALLOCATE: 4345479360 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
0: ALLOCATE: 4345482096 bytes requested; status = 2(out of memory)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[47946,1],1]
  Exit code:    127
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This node has > 180GB of available RAM. I check the Memory use with the top command:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 89681 my_user   20   0   30.1g   3.6g   2.1g R 100.0  1.9   1:39.45 pw.x
 89682 my_user   20   0   29.8g   3.2g   2.0g R 100.0  1.7   1:39.30 pw.x
```

I noticed that the process stops when RES memory reaches 4GB. This are the caracteristics of the node:

```
(base) [my_user@gpu001]$ numactl --hardware
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
node 0 size: 95313 MB
node 0 free: 41972 MB
node 1 cpus: 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
node 1 size: 96746 MB
node 1 free: 70751 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10

(base) [my_user@gpu001]$ free -lm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         192059        2561      112716         260       76781      188505
Low:         192059       79342      112716
High:             0           0           0
Swap:          8191           0        8191
```

The version of MPI is:
mpirun (Open MPI) 3.1.5

This node is a compute node in a cluster, but no matter if I submit the job with SLURM or run it directly on the node, the error is the same.
Note that I compile it on the login node and run it on this GPU node, the difference is that on the login node it has no GPU connected.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me figure out what could be going on.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you check your run-time limits with `ulimit`?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, (base) [my_user@gpu001]$ ulimit
unlimited. Also, n=2 is because the node have 2 x NVIDIA Tesla V100, so it should be one MPI process pero GPU card.

Comment: the command to run is `ulimit -a`

Comment: @Gilles   `core file size (blocks, -c) 0  
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority (-e) 0
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals (-i) 768049
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files  (-n) 100000
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority   (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes   (-u) 4096
virtual memory  (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited`

Comment: Do you log in directly into `gpu001` or do you go through an interactive job with a resource manager such as SLURM, PBS, Grid Engine, etc.? SLURM, for example, uses cgroup to set memory limits and those do not show up in `ulimit -a`.

Comment: You may check if your shell is locked in a memory cgroup with a command like `grep $$ /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/**/tasks 2>/dev/null`. `$$` expands to the PID of the shell. If there is a match and it is not in the root cgroup, i.e., not in `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks`, but in e.g. `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/SOMETHING/tasks`, then check the output of `echo /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/SOMETHING/memory.limit_in_bytes`.

Comment: QE developers said that the error is actually a failed allocation on the GPU side, not on the RAM, the RAM size is 16GB, but I am going to check your answer too. Thank you!